# Display the last modification time of a file with jQuery / Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, datetime

I would like to display the last time a json file was updated on a website.

Is there a way to read the metadata from this file and get the modification time?

I don't use a server side language, it's a static website.

I can read the json file with ajax/jQuery so I thought it would be possible to read the metadata too.

Comment: You have to read it server side. JavaScript alone won't help you. You haven't specified what server-side language you are using, and what you have tried so far. Without that we can't really help you.

Comment: Jquery is not meant to do server side processing .. hence handle it at server level ..

Comment: Anything that is client-side can't read server side information without server-side help. Even if it is a static website your webserver should still have a server side language available.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5 File API.

Refer http://www.w3.org/TR/file-upload/#dfn-file

You can use F.lastModifiedDate